# Unable to install NVIDIA driver for GeForce 1650 in Ubuntu 20.04.2

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, 20.04, graphics, nvidia-geforce

After sitting for the entire day I am still unable to figure out why NVIDIA driver is causing the boot screen with a cursor blinking and looping.My brightness is 100% and I can't change it by any other means .

I have dual booted Ubuntu 20.04.2 (LTS) along Windows 10 .
The installation was done by disabling the secure boot.

These were my attempts
After installing , I upgraded everything , and then I in "Additional Drivers" , "NVIDIA 460" was available , and I installed it . Just after a reboot , the Ubuntu shows flashing screen.
I have addedd
`nomodeset` also in the grub and updated , still no use

Then also tried changing between `lightdm` and `gdm3` still no change.
Then I tried adding `graphics-driver/ppa` and then `auto driverinstall` still story is same.
Also I manually downloading bash script from NVIDIA for 460.67.No improvements.
Even some times I was able to get inside Ubuntu `nvidia-smi` shows "Couldn't connect" error.
I alsi tried even installing CUDA , but no use

What ever method are available almost tried everything , Is there any fundamental problem causing this , how to get rid of this

My device is
Acer Aspire 7
Ryzen 5500-U
NVIDIA GTX 1650

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had many issues in my laptop which is Acer Aspire A7 with AMD Ryzen 5500U and NVIDIA GTX 1650.
After installation (dual boot) of Ubuntu, it won't boot up.

If you have installed NVIDIA Driver , remove them and follow the below steps.
In-order to fix that you have to add `nomodeset` parameter in the grub only once.
Once that is added you will be able boot into Ubuntu and login.

Next the Brightness functionality was not working , also once the NVIDIA driver (460) is installed Ubuntu won't boot up at freezes at a cursor blinking.

After spending few weeks going through the NVIDIA and Ask-Ubuntu forums , I came to know there is specific problem in Linux Kernel support for AMD Ubuntu support.

This is how I solved:
After login into Ubuntu using `nomodest` parameter

Ubuntu 20.04 has kernel of 5.8 , AMD 5000 series requires 5.10+ kernel version , in-order to upgrade this follow:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cappelikan/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mainline
```

After this

- open mainline application , by typing `mainline` in terminal.
- Select latest kernel available and install.
- remove the `nomodeset` parameter from grub, don't forget to do `sudo update-grub`, if you did this in `/etc/default/grub`, then reboot
- Make sure to disable secure boot option in BIOS
- Select the latest ubuntu kernel and login

Next we need to fix the AMD firmware to fix brightness control.The GPU of the 5xxx series will be called Cezanne, a descendant of the 4xxx Renoir GPU. Currently, it has the codename “Green Sardine” so the driver tries to load green_sardine firmware.

Now after login navigate to [https://people.freedesktop.org/~agd5f/radeon_ucode/gs/](https://people.freedesktop.org/%7Eagd5f/radeon_ucode/gs/)

- Download all of them and copy to `/lib/firmware/amdgpu`
- Then in terminal type `sudo update-initramfs -u`
- Reboot
- Now the brightness functionality should be working, now you can install NVIDIA graphics
- Add the drivers repo `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`
- Next `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices` or you can install from 'Additional Drivers'
- Install recommended driver, reboot
- `nvidia-smi` should be showing process and `nvidia-settings` will be launching NVIDIA profile

References:

- https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/ubuntu-mate-20-04-with-rtx-3070-on-ryzen-5900-black-screen-after-boot/167681/30
- [https://www.debugpoint.com/2021/01/install-nvidia-driver-ubuntu-linux/#:~:text=Install%20Nvidia%20Driver%20in%20Ubuntu%20Linux%201%20GUI,Open%20the%20application%20Nvidia%20X%20Server%20Settings.%20](https://www.debugpoint.com/2021/01/install-nvidia-driver-ubuntu-linux/#:%7E:text=Install%20Nvidia%20Driver%20in%20Ubuntu%20Linux%201%20GUI,Open%20the%20application%20Nvidia%20X%20Server%20Settings.%20)
- https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/08/mainline-install-latest-kernel-ubuntu-linux-mint/